# How to copy file without extension from remote url (Google Play Store image of app) to server's temp folder in php?

Tags: php

I am working on application of scraping structured data from Google Playstore and saving it in the database. I am getting all the structured data. I am trying to copy the `itemprop="image"` url and save the image to my server.

I have tried many things but nothing works as the file doesn't have an extension. The code below works but the either invalid file is generated or a file with zero bytes is created.

**Sample url that I am trying to copy**

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IYZe0LQOUKXpEYOyVOYYMJo4NnqBnDYkkhDgfYTgDCpuxAyy1ziBkOn0b6_LZxQ3qI4=w300-rw
```

**PHP code that I am using**

```
function getimg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'php';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);    
    // curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0); 
    $return = curl_exec($process);         
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
} 
$image="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IYZe0LQOUKXpEYOyVOYYMJo4NnqBnDYkkhDgfYTgDCpuxAyy1ziBkOn0b6_LZxQ3qI4=w300-rw";
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$length= strlen($image);
$new_string = substr($image,0,$length-8);
$imagename= basename($new_string);
$image2 = getimg($imgurl); 
$new_image_path = file_put_contents($upload_dir['basedir'].'/custom-temp/'.$imagename,$image2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code such as the `$useragent` not being named consistently and `$imgurl` being undefined. Consider turning on errors in PHP when you are debugging so that you can catch these.

I can get your code to work like this (just change the path back to `wp_upload_dir()`):

```
function getimg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $gim = 'php';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    // curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);    
    // curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0); 
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
} 
$image="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IYZe0LQOUKXpEYOyVOYYMJo4NnqBnDYkkhDgfYTgDCpuxAyy1ziBkOn0b6_LZxQ3qI4=w300-rw";
$upload_dir = "/home/laurent/test/upload";
$length= strlen($image);
$new_string = substr($image,0,$length-8);
$imagename= basename($new_string);
$image2 = getimg($image); 
$new_image_path = file_put_contents($upload_dir.'/'.$imagename,$image2);
```

Comment: i tried you code the file is being copied but its zero bytes file

Comment: It works for me, it creates a 94K file. What happens is you add `var_dump($return)` below `curl_exec`?

Comment: when i do `var_dump($return)` it returns `bool(false)`

Comment: Hmm, that should just work. Are you passing the right URL? How about `var_dump($url)`?

Comment: i am getting this result when i do `var_dump($url)` `string(87) "//lh4.ggpht.com/kvfvBEmjhHjpafyET74YBxHah-yZKXsvdLe8yfUJkg9pXXFR2rTmWPAaRo4ZrGC99Q=w300"` this is a different url than the question as i am running it in a counter